# Multiple rows using pivot in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table.

```
Item  | ID
--------------
1-A   | 213
2-B   | 432
3-C   | 267
3-C   | 879
3-C   | 467
```

I use pivot.

```
Select * from (
    Select ID,Item
    From data1
)R
Pivot (
    Max(ID) For Item 
    in 
    ([1-A],[2-B],[3-C])
)as pvt
```

But I can only get one value.

```
1-A  | 2-B | 3-C
-----------------
213  | 453 | 467
```

How can I get all the values of 3-C, I hope I can get this result.

```
1-A  | 2-B | 3-C | 3-C | 3-C
---------------------------
213  | 453 | 267 | 879 | 467
```

But 3-C, there may be one or more, I cannot control how many will appear.

Hope to help answer, thank you.

Comment: How many rows could there be, is it always 5? What determines the order of said rows when they have the same value for `Item` (as it is clearly not `ID`) or does the order not matter?

Comment: Currently only 3-C will have multiple, at least one, and at most many,That is, there will be multiple 3-C situations

Comment: "At most many"? *Many* isn't a number. Does that mean that there is an indeterminable about of rows? What about the rest I asked in my comment..?

Comment: Yes,an indeterminable of rows,and order not matter.If it is possible,, I hope it will be shown according to my results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem here is that you have an indeterminable number of rows. This means you need dynamic SQL, The next problem is that you don't have unique values to pivot on, so we need to get inventive with `ROW_NUMBER` as well. This gives this, which is not particularly pretty, but "works".

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Item char(3),
                            ID int);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Item,
                           ID)
VALUES('1-A',213),
      ('2-B',432),
      ('3-C',267),
      ('3-C',879),
      ('3-C',467);
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(30) = N',' + @CRLF + N'       ';

WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT Item,
           ID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Item) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT @SQL = N'WITH RNs AS(' + @CRLF +
              N'    SELECT Item,' + @CRLF +
              N'           ID,' + @CRLF +
              N'           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Item) AS RN' + @CRLF +
              N'    FROM dbo.YourTable)' + @CRLF +
              N'SELECT ' +
              STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'MAX(CASE WHEN Item = ',QUOTENAME(R.Item,''''),N' AND RN = ',R.RN,N' THEN R.ID END) AS ',QUOTENAME(R.Item)),@Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY R.Item, R.RN) + @CRLF + 
              N'FROM RNs R;'
FROM RNs R;

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

I have *assumed* you are using a recent version of SQL Server. If not, you will need to replace `STRING_AGG` with the older `FOR XML PATH` method.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=08bd4bebf9917dcd972377eec45819bf)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `Dynamic SQL` since you have an unknown number of columns. The query is form dynamically and use `sp_executesql` to execute the query

Looks like you wanted a distinct value of `Item` & `ID` combination, so I use `GROUP BY Item, ID` here.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = isnull(@sql + ',', 'SELECT ')
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ID) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(Item)
FROM   data1
GROUP BY Item, ID
ORDER BY Item, ID

-- PRINT @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Example : [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a25b1d78a62130fee13c63130150205)

Comment: You appar to have lost a row; you have 5 columns but 6 rows in the fiddle.

Comment: 2 of the rows are identical. I doubt OP wanted duplicate Item & ID value. It is intentionally added to illustrate that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be to put the results in a single column for `3-C` values, using `string_agg()`:

```
select string_agg(case when item = '[1-A]' then id end, ',') within group (order by id) as id_1_a,
       string_agg(case when item = '[2-B]' then id end, ',') within group (order by id) as id_2_b,
       string_agg(case when item = '[3-C]' then id end, ',') within group (order by id) as id_3_c
from data1;
```

This is not the exact result set you specify, but it might accomplish what you need.